# how to level out basement cement crack

Tags: basement, flooring, cement

I plan on laying some vinyl planks onto cement but there are some cracks from leveling in the cement and with the new flooring you can "feel" where the cement barely sticks up at the crack.[image]

Wasn't a problem with carpet but is now.  These are hairline cracks but you can feel them underfoot.

This seems to be a slightly different question than some out there because it's how to both "level and fill" at the crack location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we ended up doing is grinding down the "lip" of the highest edge with an angle grinder cement grinding wheel

[image].

Then we filled the hole with "self leveling" concrete sealant.  Sikaflex for instance.  Over fill a bit, then after it dries, came back and scraped off any sealant that was poking up with a 4" big blade scraper.[image]

Comment: I use masionary grinding wheels for cracks that are offset as I have knocked the inserts out of single row surfacing grinders but never had trouble a double row like you show.